# error while running `ng-packagr -p ng-package.json`

Tags: angular, package, ng-packagr

I'm trying to make an angular package with `ng-packagr`.
but when I run this command : `ng-packagr -p ng-package.json` I get this error:
`cannot find module '@angular/compiler-cli'`
I checked everything. I have the latest versions of all modules and `@angular/cli` and `node`. I installed `tsickle` package too. but still getting this error and can't create a package.
can you suggest any other solutions?

Comment: npm i  @angular/compiler-cli -g ?

Comment: should `@angular/compiler-cli` be installed globally?

Comment: I don' think so, just a suggestion to try it.

Comment: it doesn't make any difference

Answer (score 0):

Try remove `node_modules` then `run npm install`
check the output you may need to install missing packages manually,
this worked for me when I got `Error: Cannot find module 'tsickle/src/tsickle'`